# Android DIV image changed, when clicked on the page

Tags: android, image, web-applications, html, popup

If you open any popup image in the Android browser, then click in any place on the page, the image is being changed (colors/sharpness/whatever - I can't define precisely, since I'm not an artist).

To see this effect, open a site with a popup image, which is implemented as a div with absolute positioning (say, http://highslide.com/ -- the first site I've googled). The site should be open in the Android browser (I've tried Android emulator from Eclipse ADT plugin and Kindle Fire). Click on any preview to popup the image, then tap on the page (keep you finger on the screen) and look at the image the same time.

My question: what this effect is about and **how to eliminate it**? Why don't I see it neither on PC nor on Mobile Safari? I have the same effect with my web-app, where it looks ugly and seems to be slowing a form, so I want to get rid of it.

A figure:

[image]

I've enlarged a portions of two shots, made **before** tapping on the arrow point, and **after**, and inserted them on top to show what I'm talking about.

Regards,

Comment: This is just the way the images are download its for performance. Just like how different levels of video encoding work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every image on the page has the same physical size as specified in HTML/CSS, this effect disappears. That's why I observed this in popups: their inner images usually are resized.

I have mixed feelings. Kinda satisfaction for finding it after all and hatred to Android developers for programming this feature.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your web app or your web page, this is simply a performance feature of Android.  You can see this on the homescreen when you scroll and it happens in any application that scrolls.

When you tap, it signals to Android that you might potentially start scrolling.  To prepare for this, it uses a compressed version of the images to make scrolling smoother.

You don't see this on your PC because your PC has no problem scrolling through a web page with tons of images at full resolution.  As to why you don't see it on mobile safari, I don't know enough about the platform to say.

Comment: That's nice, thank you, but how can I disable this harmful feature? Is it possible at all? Imagine, you are playing Angry Birds, HTML5 version, tapping the screen and "it signals to Android that you might potentially start scrolling. To prepare for this, it uses a compressed version of the images".

Comment: I have full control on WebView-based application, is there a setting in it?

Comment: This is a setting on the handset that you have no control over as a web page.  This thread (http://androidforums.com/captivate-support-troubleshooting/157862-image-degradation-when-scrolling.html) seems to indicate that LauncherPro has an option for high-quality scrolling.

Comment: It looks like this can help (from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html): setEnableSmoothTransition(boolean enable)
Set whether the WebView will enable smooth transition while panning or zooming or while the window hosting the WebView does not have focus.

Comment: Will try as soon as I can, report on results.